# Set recipient routing order

Tags: api, soap, docusignapi

```
 for (int recCount = 0; recCount < recipientList.Count; recCount++)
        {
            // Construct the recipients
            var r1 = new Recipient
            {
                UserName = recipientList[recCount].RecipientName,
                Email = recipientList[recCount].RecipientEmail,

                ID = (recCount + 1).ToString(),
                Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer,
                RoutingOrder = (ushort)(recCount + 1)

                //CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo { ClientUserId = i.ToString() }
            };
            runningList.Add(r1);
        }
```

i set routing of recipient in loop and send envelope using createandsendevelope method but it will reset all recipient to same order 1 .Is there any configuration required or it will be work for only certain conditions

Comment: Is your request setting them to 1 or is data in the envelope set to 1 unexpectedly?

Comment: I have check log it will become 1 for all unexpectedly

Comment: Can you post what you're actually sending to DocuSign?

Comment: I m using CreateandSendEnvelope method of SOAP API .Net.I passing Envelope object in it.I have set Recipients list  in Envelope object as I poseted

Comment: I also tried to pass statically in sequence routing number but It will become  1 for all reciepients

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's interesting with service references and .NET is an additional parameter that gets generated for some properties. For routing order, there's an additional parameter named RoutingOrderSpecified, which indicates if you have set the RoutingOrder. This is not present in the WSDL -- it is generated when you added api.asmx as a service reference.

So, to set your routing order, you must additionally set RoutingOrderSpecified to true.

I got this resolution from DocuSign Support Community post and It works for me

http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-NET-READ-ONLY/Recipient-RoutingOrder-not-working/td-p/1885